# GPUimage framework display error in device that has iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I am am using the `GPUImage` **framework** in my app. Its working great, But when i tried to run app in device that has `iOS 7.1` its display following error.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-fhjyuaovocdkvnfdpxllwvwplxei/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGPUImage.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-fhjyuaovocdkvnfdpxllwvwplxei/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGPUImage.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageContrastFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageSaturationFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageExposureFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in WSCall.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageGrayscaleFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImagePicture", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in WSCall.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageBrightnessFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageSharpenFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in WSCall.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It is working on **Simulator** and my other device which has `iOS 7.0.3`.

Comment: Try cleaning the project and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

Should modify valid architectures armv7 => armv7s, arm64

Comment: If i do this it will display error that `No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 and armv7s' + ', VALID_ARCHS=arm64 armv7s).`